# Use C# WPF user control in VB.NET Winforms forms

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms

I have a legacy project in VB.net which also uses winforms. I wan to see if I can use WPF `UserControl`s that I wrote in another project. This other project is in C#. I am able to create a project reference and I can access the class in the C# project. If I try to add the `UserControl` to a panel. I get an error.

`panel1.Controls.Add(_ucUserControl)`

The error says:

> Value of type `ucUserControl` cannot be converted to `Control`

Does someone know how I can do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0

Comment: You can't simply use WPF controls inside Winforms. You need an ElementHost control and it'll contain the WPF content within the form.